# Should I use autolayout for gesture dragging, rotating, scaling?

Tags: ios, autolayout, gesture

I am implementing a gesture to drag, rotate, scale a view. I wonder should I use autolayout constraint or just manipulating the frame or transform. So I just use autolayout for the initial layout. Should I remove all the constraint when the first layout is finished if I only autolayout for initial layout

Comment: Yes, you can use for dragging and scaling. I never tried rotating the view with autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is possible only using affine transforms on layer.

My vote is using manual layout which gives you wide abilities to make manual things: moving, rotation and whatever you want without fighting and trying to workaround AutoLayout.